# WHM's Exim Advanced Editor not accepting settings for DKIM

Tags: email, whm, dkim

I'm running Centos 6.7 and WHM 54.0, with Exim running on it: `Exim version 4.86_1 #1 built 04-Mar-2016 17:12:16`

I'm trying to configure DKIM for my outbound mail, which in part I've mostly got working. The problem I have is that the changes I make to my exim.conf work, but get overwritten from time to time with updates to Exim and/or WHM, as my changes seem to last a little over a week. From what I understand, this file gets built from a number of source files including *exim.conf.local*. It seems that the correct way to edit this file is by making changes to it in WHM under the "Advanced Editor" in the Exim Configuration Manager:

So in that, I populate section `TRANSPORTMIDDLE` with all my transports. When I do, the tick goes green - but it won't save the configuration.

Its keeps coming back with the following error:

> Your configuration could not be updated.
>
> Doing Dry Run Dry Run failed Configuration file has an invalid syntax. Please try the edit again.
>
> Error message from syntax check: 2016-04-21 10:32:51 Exim configuration error: there are two transports called "mailman_virtual_transport"

Looking at the output file that is has tried to generate, I can see it has duplicated what I've added with the old settings present in the file. It hasn't overwritten the original transport settings nor changed them.

So - question - what is the correct way to change the following transport settings

`dkim_remote_smtp: driver = smtp interface = <; ${if exists {/etc/mailips}{${lookup{${lc:$original_domain}}lsearch{/etc/mailips}{$value}{${lookup{${lc:$sender_address_domain}}lsearch{/etc/mailips}{$value}{${lookup{${perl{get_sender_from_uid}}}lsearch*{/etc/mailips}{$value}{}}}}}}}} helo_data = ${if exists {/etc/mailhelo}{${lookup{${lc:$original_domain}}lsearch{/etc/mailhelo}{$value}{${lookup{${lc:$sender_address_domain}}lsearch{/etc/mailhelo}{$value}{${lookup{${perl{get_sender_from_uid}}}lsearch*{/etc/mailhelo}{$value}{$primary_hostname}}}}}}}{$primary_hostname}} dkim_domain = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}} dkim_selector = x dkim_private_key = "/etc/dkim.private.key" dkim_canon = relaxed`

When researching this topic, I can only find posts around 2010 / 2012 - suggesting that these changes can't be made in the advanced editor - is this still the case? I would certainly like to learn to configure this the correct way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is appears to be about system and network administration and would be better suited to ServerFault.

Comment: Contact cPanel support because its product of cPanel they know better